# match namespace case insensitive in Catalyst controller 

Tags: perl, catalyst

```
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => 'Hello')
```

Now consider I have above statement in my catalyst controller `Hello.pm`.
This will match `http://localhost:3000/Hello` in url.
But I also want to match `http://localhost:3000/hello`.

One way I tried to achieve this like below

```
sub match_hello : Path('/hello')
{
my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
$c->response->body("lowercase hello also matched"); 

}
```

But, Can we also achieve same using `__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => ... )` statement?

Answer (score 0):

No need to mess with namespaces. Read [*Action types* in `Catalyst::Manual::Intro`](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro#Action-types).

Add a `LocalRegex` action to the root controller.

```
sub match_hello :LocalRegex('(?i)^hello$') {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->response->body('case-insensitive hello matches');
}
```

Debug output:

```
[debug] Loaded Regex actions:
.-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------.
| Regex                               | Private                              |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| ^(?:.*?)(?i)^hello$                 | /match_hello                         |
'-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------'
```

Request:

```
$ GET http://localhost:5000/HeLlO
case-insensitive hello matches
```

Comment: your solution doesn't run when `__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => 'Hello');` statement is present.However it works if namespace is empty i.e. `__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');`I want solution with `Hello` namespace and this `Hello` should be case insensitive.

Comment: @daxim- one change required in your solution is `Regex` action instead of `LocalRegex`.Then It will work. However still It will only match a single method and not the controller.